# Single query to replace a value in multiple tables with same column

Tags: postgresql, update, postgresql-9.4, dynamic-sql

I am using Postgres SQL. I am having multiple tables say `table1`, `table2`, `table3`, `table4`, ... with a common column say `name` in each of the tables. I want to replace a the value 'Jhon' with 'Jimmy' in every `name` column with a single query.

Presently I am using below query:

```
update table1 set "name" = 'Jimmy' where "name" = 'Jhon';
```

But I have to run one by one for every table in database. Please suggest a single query which can do the task.

Comment: Is the issue having to commit all of the updates to all tables at once, or is the issue needing to update a lot of values (more than just Jhon -> Jimmy) on those tables?

Comment: Why the `mysql` tag if you are using Postgres?

Comment: Why do you have so many tables with the same structure and information? That sounds like a terrible design.

Answer (score 1):

To just generate `UPDATE` statements:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_update_all(_old_val text, _new_val text
                                      , VARIADIC _tbls regclass[])
  RETURNS SETOF text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _tbl regclass;
BEGIN
   FOREACH _tbl IN ARRAY _tbls
   LOOP
      RETURN NEXT 'UPDATE ' || _tbl || ' SET name = $2 WHERE name = $1;';
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

To execute dynamically:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_update_all(_old_val text, _new_val text
                                      , VARIADIC _tbls regclass[])
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _tbl regclass;
BEGIN
   FOREACH _tbl IN ARRAY _tbls
   LOOP
      EXECUTE 'UPDATE ' || _tbl || ' SET name = $2 WHERE name = $1'
      USING $1, $2;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=459225f0249a07cedbc6f70663fe806c)*

About `VARIADIC`:

- [Pass multiple values in single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19204560/939860)

About `FOREACH`:

- [Postgres - array for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9784986/939860)

About passing and concatenating ***table names*** safely:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860)

And pass ***values*** safely with the [`USING` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).